Can't install XRDP on ec2 instance?
I followed this tutorial here:
Connecting to AWS EC2 instance through remote desktop
And I swear, in the past, that it worked flawlessly. But now, I am getting errors.
Err:1 http://us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble/universe amd64 libfuse2t64 amd64 2.9.9-8.1build1
  Temporary failure resolving 'us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com'
Err:2 http://us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble/universe amd64 xrdp amd64 0.9.24-4
  Temporary failure resolving 'us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com'
Err:3 http://us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble/universe amd64 libpipewire-0.3-modules-xrdp amd64 0.2-2
  Temporary failure resolving 'us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com'
Err:4 http://us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble/universe amd64 pipewire-module-xrdp all 0.2-2
  Temporary failure resolving 'us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com'
Err:5 http://us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble/universe amd64 xorgxrdp amd64 1:0.9.19-1
  Temporary failure resolving 'us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com'
E: Failed to fetch http://us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/f/fuse/libfuse2t64_2.9.9-8.1build1_amd64.deb  Temporary failure resolving 'us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com'
E: Failed to fetch http://us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/x/xrdp/xrdp_0.9.24-4_amd64.deb  Temporary failure resolving 'us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com'
E: Failed to fetch http://us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/p/pipewire-module-xrdp/libpipewire-0.3-modules-xrdp_0.2-2_amd64.deb  Temporary failure resolving 'us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com'
E: Failed to fetch http://us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/p/pipewire-module-xrdp/pipewire-module-xrdp_0.2-2_all.deb  Temporary failure resolving 'us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com'
E: Failed to fetch http://us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/x/xorgxrdp/xorgxrdp_0.9.19-1_amd64.deb  Temporary failure resolving 'us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com'
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?

Any ideas on how to get past this issue? Much appreciated. Thank you!

Check your DNS. /etc/resolv.conf and network: ping 1.1.1.1

Output from /etc/resolve.conf is below. And I successfully able to ping 1.1.1.1...

sudo cat /etc/resolv.conf
#Some default notes within file...#
nameserver 127.0.0.53
options edns0 trust-ad
search .

If ping 1.1.1.1 is OK, you have a DNS issue

I have two IPs: dig @127.0.0.53 +short A stackoverflow.com

What is the output of ip -a and/or ifconfig?
